Formal definition of a Category
First, let us consider the definition of a monoid:
Definition. Let $X$ be a set, let $*$ be a binary operation on $X$, and let $e\in X$. We say that $(X,*,e)$ is a monoid, iff, the next properties are satisfied:
(1) For all $a,b,c\in X$, it holds $a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c$.
(2) For all $a\in X$, it holds $a*e=a=e*a$.
Note that this definition has a certain style. We first give a context Let $X$ be a set, let $*$ be a binary operation on $X$, and let $ e\in X$, and then we say under what conditions these pieces of information are considered as a monoid. We can define almost all mathematical objects following this style, almost all because there are not a definition of a category following this style. All of the definitions of a category don't follow this style, they instead begin with A category consists of. Why is that so? Why are there no definitions of a category with the same style as the monoid's definition?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Apart from philosophical issues, certainly there is a way in which "sets" enter (middle-of-the-road) category theory: while the collection of all objects in a category is "allowed" to be a proper class (that is, too large to be a set), the hom-sets $Hom(A,B)$ for objects $A,B$ are required to be sets.
Otherwise, there'd be problems in abstracting the notions of composition, etc.
It is certainly possible to abstract-away this issue, but, still, it might be interesting that, at least historically, this was the constraint. :)
